# Add singleton Kafka producer: attempted to read or write protected memory

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, apache-kafka

in .net core Startup.cs ConfigureServices method  i have register kafka producer instance as singleton, then I passed the object as a parameter to the constructor of any class in the middle layer as an interface. In some cases I get "Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt." error.

```
services.AddSingleton<IProducer<Null, string>>(provider => new ProducerBuilder<Null, string>(conf).Build());

using (IProducer<Null, string> producer = new ProducerBuilder<Null, string>(conf).Build())
{
    services.AddSingleton<IProducer<Null, string>>(provider => producer);
}
```

what is the difference in these codes.

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // ... some codes
        services.AddSingleton<IProducer<Null, string>>( provider => new ProducerBuilder<Null, string>(conf).Build());

        using (IProducer<Null, string> producer = new ProducerBuilder<Null, string>(conf).Build())
        {
            services.AddSingleton<IProducer<Null, string>>(provider => producer);
        }
    }
}
```

Error location:

```
public MessageMutation(IHubContext<MessageHub, ITypedHubClient> messageContext, IProducer<Null, string> producer)
{
    // some codes...

    producer.Produce("my-topic", new Message<Null, string> { Value = message.Value }, handler);

    // some codes..
}
```

Comment: `services.AddSingleton<IProducer<Null, string>>( provider => producer );` Given you disposed of `producer`, see https://github.com/confluentinc/confluent-kafka-dotnet/issues/1008 for why that is a bad idea.

Comment: I lit up. Thanks for the clean answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error may come because you are disposing your producer. Singleton objects should have lifetime of the application (which basically the definition of a singleton).

`using(IProducer<Null, string> producer = new ProducerBuilder<Null, string>(conf).Build())` is shorthand (syntactic sugar) for

```
IProducer<Null, string> producer = null;
try
{
    producer = new ProducerBuilder<Null, string>(conf).Build();

    // do sth
}
finally
{
    producer?.Dispose();
}
```

But when you dispose an object, you free up it's resources, so it can't be actually used afterwards